# Installing a specific toolchain in android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, toolchain

I am trying to build a project that requires
`arm-linux-androideabi-4.8`.

How do I specifically install `arm-linux-androideabi-4.8` alone?

Answer (score 0):

You can't install a subset of the NDK. It's only available as a monolithic package.

Comment: When I installed android ndk, I got arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 . how do I get around it?

Comment: Are you asking how to get an old GCC? You need an old NDK if you want an old GCC.

Comment: well I wanted an arm-linux-androideabi-4.8 so does that mean that I install an older ndk?

Answer (score 0):

download  android-ndk-r14b-linux-x86_64.zip
to download type this

```
cd / 
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r14b-linux-x86_64.zip
```

to unzip

```
unzip android-ndk-r14b-linux-x86_64.zip
```

to build

```
cd /android-ndk-r14b
cd build/tools
export TOOLCHAIN=/android-toolchain
./make_standalone_toolchain.py --arch arm --api 19 --install-dir /android-toolchain
```